# Datos en función de activación escalón

Tags: python, redes-neuronales

Estoy siguiendo un ejemplo de perceptrón para una puerta lógica AND. La función de activación que requiero es una de escalón, pero en el ejemplo se usa sigmoide. Cargué una función, pero al pasar los datos por ella manda el error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

¿Cómo puedo resolver este error para poder usar esa función?

```py
datos = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[1]])

pesos = np.random.normal(scale = 0.5, size = (2,1))

def step(z):
  return 1 if z >= 0 else 0

output = step(np.dot(datos,pesos))
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo está dando porque estás intentado comparar una matriz de tipo `numpy.ndarray` con varios elementos a un número.

Como bien te indica en el error, debes utilizar `.any()` para comprobar si algún número de `z` es mayor o igual a 0, o `.all()` para devolver `True` únicamente si todos los elementos de `z` son mayores o iguales a 0.

Un ejemplo de la función correcta sería este:

```
def step(z: np.ndarray): return 1 if z.any() >= 0 else 0
```